# DataTable with ajax reload blacks out the screen if typing too fast

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, reload

I've got a table that I'm using DataTables with and reloading it with ajax. The table is a basic table:

```
<table class="table table-striped at-table" id="tblAccountModel">
    <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountId)
               </th>
               <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
               </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody class="mousechange">

       </tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript to set it up is:

```
$(function () {
    oTable = $('#tblAccountModel').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "paginate": true,
        "ajaxSource": "/Finance/AccountListAjax",
        "processing": true,
        "serverMethod": "GET",
        "displayLength": 50,
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            if (20 > oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) {
                $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
                $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_length').hide();
            }
        }

    });
```

When I type something in the search box, it kind of looks like it's loading after each key press. If I type really fast, it loads a lot and the background gets darker, eventually going all black if I typed enough. When exiting the modal the background is darkened like the modal is still there and I can't interact with the screen.

How to prevent this, or how to prevent it from trying to load on every new character??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatables search is triggered by the keyup event of the search input, so every key press will make a request to the server. There are a number of ways to modify this behaviour: You can unbind the keyup event like this:

```
$("div.dataTables_filter input").unbind();
```

and  trigger the search from the return keypress:

```
$("div.dataTables_filter input").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            oTable.search(this.value).draw();
        }
 });
```

Or trigger the search from a form submit event:

```
$("#form-filter").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchTerm = $('#filter input').val();
        oTable.search(searchTerm).draw();
});
```

There is also a plugin which will add a 'delay', so the request is made after typing:

https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnSetFilteringDelay

Which you attach to the searchbox keyup event:

```
var searchDelay = null;
$('div.dataTables_filter input').on('keyup', function () {
      var search = $('div.dataTables_filter input').val();

       clearTimeout(searchDelay);

       searchDelay = setTimeout(function () {
           if (search != null) {
               oTable.search(search).draw();
           }
       }, 750);
  });
```

Comment: In that plugin it said that new versions of DataTables has a searchDelay parameter.. The default is 400ms but that was too quick in my case... I slowed it up to 800ms and that did the trick. Thanks!